# Why can't I call my function inside a .on?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to define the functions as variables before using it, apparently then I can use **$(this).off('mouseleave', fadeOutt)** to turn it off and  **$(this).on('mouseleave', fadeOutt)** to turn it back on again.

Why does this work:

```
    var fadeDarl = function(){         
$("#darl").on({ 
    mouseenter: function(){
        $("#bgimg1").stop(true,true).fadeIn(200);
},
    mouseleave: function() {
        $("#bgimg1").stop(true,true).fadeOut(200);
}
});
};

fadeDarl();
```

but not this:

```
var fadeInn = function() {

   $("#bgimg1").stop(true,true).fadeIn(200);
};
var fadeOutt = function() {

    $("#bgimg1").stop(true,true).fadeOut(200);

};

    var fadeDarl = function(){         
$("#darl").on({ 
    mouseenter: fadeInn(),
    mouseleave: fadeOutt()
});
};

fadeDarl();
```

Comment: **Remove `()`**. Code: `$("#darl").on({ 
    mouseenter: fadeInn,
    mouseleave: fadeOutt
});`

Answer (score 2):

In this code:

```
 var fadeDarl = function(){         
$("#darl").on({ 
    mouseenter: fadeInn(),
    mouseleave: fadeOutt()
});
};
```

when you put parentheses after `fadeInn`, you call that function and assign its return value to `mouseenter`.

What you really want to do is to assign the *function itself* to `mouseenter`, so that the function can be called later when the specified event fires.
So just remove those parentheses and it will work as expected.

This might confuse you if you come from a language where functions can't be passed by reference, but in JavaScript functions are [first-class objects](http://helephant.com/2008/08/19/functions-are-first-class-objects-in-javascript/).

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass function instead of calling it:

Change

```
$("#darl").on({ 
    mouseenter: fadeInn(),
    mouseleave: fadeOutt()
});
```

to

```
$("#darl").on({ 
    mouseenter: fadeInn,
    mouseleave: fadeOutt
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the parenthesis. You are invoking the function and returning the value, not assigning the function to the event.

```
mouseenter: fadeInn(),
mouseleave: fadeOutt()
```

Answer (score 1):

you were passing evaluation/result of function not function itself, it should be:

```
$("#darl").on({ 
    mouseenter: fadeInn,
    mouseleave: fadeOutt
});
```

Answer (score 1):

who said you can't just change fadeInn() to fadeInn

Answer (score 1):

when you  do `mouseenter: fadeInn()` then you are binding mouseenter event with the return value of fadeIn(). 
So, that function will be called only once at the time of binding and then  on mouseenter it will try to call return value i.e undefined. 
So instead of binding the return value you should do

```
mouseenter: fadeInn
```

that will do the work

Answer (score 0):

Honestly you should use the right tool for the right job. This is the stuff css was built for. Plus you will get the animation hardware accelerated by the gpu not the cpu and you wont lock up the single thread of js. The only time I would favor js animtions over css is when I needed to hook into the events in the animation lifecycle, or needed a more complicated animation like a tween.

```css
#darl figure {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: .2s all;
  display: inline-block;
}

#darl:hover figure {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div id="darl">
  <p>I am a div. there are many like me but this one is me</p>
  <figure id="bgimg1" class="fade_wrapper">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100" />
    <figcaption>lorem pixel yall</figcaption>
  </figure>
</div>
```

Comment: I needed to use jquery because I was making something that would expand, then stop listening to mouseenter/leave and then when you closed it it would start again... I mightve been able to do it with addClass and removeClass maybe...